# How to hide a div from code (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div element on my page that I wish to show/hide based on a session value in my code-behind. How can I do this?

Comment: Hide it or remove it completely?

Comment: do you want to remove or hide?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Mr Muhammad and Richard. I got the solution for this from Mr Buzz.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Give the div `"runat="server"` and an `id` and you can reference it in your `code behind`.

```
<div runat="server" id="theDiv">
```

In code behind:

```
{
    theDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without runat="server" ?

Comment: @SalGad not if you want to hide it using `C#`, the `runat="server"` makes it accessible to the CodeBehind where `C#` runs.

Comment: @SalGad @Bazzz is right. You need to specify `runat="server"` if you want to do it in C#, as without it your C# code-behind will not "know" of your `<div>` element.

Comment: @SalGad you can do it but that would be a workaround. You can wait for the page to load in your JS and then do something. Not a clear solution - but just to answer your question - yes there is a way to do it.

Comment: if you don't want to use runat=server you'll have to hide it from the front end (javascript)

Answer (score 12):

if your div has the runat set to server, you surely can do a `myDiv.Visible = false` in your `Page_PreRender` event for example.

if you need help on using the session, have a look in msdn, it's very easy.

Comment: You may also find this page useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 9):

one fast and simple way is to make the div as

```
<div runat="server" id="MyDiv"></div>
```

and on code behind you set `MyDiv.Visible=false`

Answer (score 8):

In the Html

```
<div id="AssignUniqueId" runat="server">.....BLAH......<div/>
```

In the code

```
public void Page_Load(object source, Event Args e)
{

   if(Session["Something"] == "ShowDiv")
      AssignUniqueId.Visible = true;
    else
      AssignUniqueID.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this. Your markup:

```
<div id="MyId" runat="server">some content</div>
```

.. and in aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["someSessionVal"].ToString() == "some value")
    {
        MyId.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MyId.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh. `if(condition) { prop = true; } else { prop = false; }`? There's a simpler way to write that.

Comment: @Damien - Agreed. ie. prop = condition. But I wanted to maximise readability. I guess readability is debatable though! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Give the div "runat="server" and an id and you can reference it in your code behind.

```
<div runat="server" id="theDiv">
```

In code behind:

```
{
    theDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

In Designer.cs page:

```
 protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl theDiv;
```

Answer (score 3):

work with you apply runat="server" in your div section...

```
<div runat="server" id="hideid">
```

On your button click event:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      hideid.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

u can also try from yours design

```
    <div <%=If(True = True, "style='display: none;'", "")%> >True</div>
<div <%=If(True = False, "style='display: none;'", "")%> >False</div>
<div <%=If(Session.Item("NameExist") IsNot Nothing, "style='display: none;'", "")%> >NameExist</div>
<div <%=If(Session.Item("NameNotExist") IsNot Nothing, "style='display: none;'", "")%> >NameNotExist</div>
```

Output html

```
    <div style='display: none;' > True</div>
<div  >False</div>
<div style='display: none;' >NameExist</div>
<div  >NameNotExist</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are fine but I would add to be sure the div is defined in the designer.cs file. This doesn't always happen when adding a div to the .aspx file. Not sure why but there are threads concerning this issue in this forum.
Eg:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl theDiv;
```

Answer (score 0):

In code behind:

```
{
    yourDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be hidden using jquery.
The list to be hidden/shown can be retrieved from the MVC controller/code-behind using an ajax call.