# Trying to set a html property based on a code behind value

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying the following:

```
<div id='divOwner' runat=server visible='<%# isAccountOwner(Me.UserId) %>'>
```

I would expect this to switch visible / invisible based on the value of isAccountOwner.  This is not working as expected, and is always coming up visible. Can somebody enlighten me please?

Thanks

Comment: isn't it should be on style attribute? like style="visibility:hidden or visible"

Comment: try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297165/how-to-hide-a-div-from-code-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#`in code nuggets (<% %>) is used with data bound controls like gridview, repeater control etc. For your div to work like this you need to call the `DataBind` method of this Div or one of its paremt control.

So, In page load include this line:-

```
divOwner.DataBind();
```

And make sure `isAccountOwner` returns a Boolean.