# hide and show asp.net (div) by using a c# code, how can I do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net element (form) with a next button, I want when the user click on the button the first div  hide and the second div shows by using a c# code.

Comment: Sound like the sort of thing you should be doing in javascript.  If you want to do it in c# you will have to do it server side so post back the form basically.

Comment: Do you have search ?

Comment: Why do you want to involve a post-back to the server just to hide an element?  Is this WebForms or MVC?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a div from code (c#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297165/how-to-hide-a-div-from-code-c)

Comment: Ben Robinson yes I want to do it on server side

Comment: binard No I don't have search

Comment: David I want to make it hide with a c# code because I don't want that element shows in the Inspect Element with google chrome or any other browser .

Comment: Slappywag thank you I will see it :)

Comment: @Saif Next time try searching first. If you had entered your question title into Google the first result would have been my link

Comment: really @Slappywag thank you anyway I have tried this solution before:
protected void btnNextPartOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PanelPartOne.Visible = false;
            PanelPartTwo.Visible = true;
            PanelPartThree.Visible = false;
        }

and it dose not work

Comment: Seriously this question has had 24 views *(at time of posting)* and no one has bothered to edit out the Classic ASP tag? It's quite clearly .Net related!

Comment: @Lankymart Not everyone who views the question has ASP or .NET knowledge.

Comment: @TylerH I do agree however looking at the comments and the answers certain ones realise its a .Net question but don't bother to take the 2 seconds to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it

markup:

```
<div id="firstdiv" runat="server"></div>
<div id="seconddiv" runat="server"></div>
```

C#:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstdiv.Visible = false;
    seconddiv.Visible = true;
}
```

You can expand from this as required.

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat = "server"` and `id` to the `<div>` you want to show/hide. Then in the server-side C# code you can hide, like this:

```
var theDiv = YourDivById as HtmlGenericControl;

if (theDiv != null)
{
    theDiv.Style.Add ("Display", "none");
}
```